# Meteor: How to pass a value to a Meteor.settings variable from terminal?

Tags: meteor, configuration, terminal, settings, env

Here is a code I have in my serveur directory in a file called main.js:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        return Meteor.Mandrill.config({
            username: Meteor.settings.username_mail,
            key: Meteor.settings.key_mail
        });
    });

    }
```

I am using Mandrill to send e-mail and I would like to know how can I set the following

```
username: Meteor.settings.username_mail,
key: Meteor.settings.key_mail
```

I tried to run `export METEOR_SETTINGS='{"username_mail":"user@mail.com", "key_mail":"fjbvbfvbfbvfjvf”}’` in my terminal but is does not work. I just can not figure out a way to configure it form the terminal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meteor --settings yoursettings.json

If only there were some official docs which explained such basic things.

Comment: But I do not want yoursettings.json to display my keys in my git repository ? That is why I want to use ENV variables the same way I do with rails. With rails I just have to set the ENV with the terminal and that is it. Should I use yoursettings.json with gitignore then ?

Comment: yes, use .gitignore. If you have a secure storage then provide a full path to yoursettings.json. Environment variables are no more secure than a file on an encrypted partition.